# What is a carriage bolt washer with mounting spikes called?

Tags: washer

The "washer" below is from a carriage bolt. It's like a t-nut, but used on the square side of a carriage bolt and holds it steady. I'd love to get my hands on a box of these but can't for the life of me Google the correct terms. Hopefully someone here will be able to point me in the right direction.

For what it's worth, the "washer" came from an older kids playset that was custom built.

[image: carriage bolt washer]

Comment: If you're desperate then normal washers will do.  To replicate something similar, use an oversized washer, and put some small cuts in the side with a hacksaw.  Then bend the very edge over in a vice to create the teeth.  Finish up with some zinc cold galv spray for rust prevention.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is a toothed or pronged "[torque washer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washer_(hardware)#Plain_washers)". As you suspect, it's intended to prevent a carriage bolt from turning in soft wood.

Answer (score 1):

Get these at Menards. Galvanized Torque Washers, 10 in a package.

Comment: This duplicates isherwood's answer

Answer (score 0):

These are also called a "Pronged Washer".